# Property of natural homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $A\unlhd G$ and $H\leq G$. Suppose that $\phi : G \rightarrow G/A$ denotes the natural homomorphism. if $HA = gHg^{-1}$A then $\phi(H) = \phi(gHg^{-1})$.

I know that $\phi(HA) = \phi(H)\phi(A)$ so $\phi(H)\phi(A) = \phi(gHg^{-1})\phi(A)$. Also $\phi(A) = A$ which is the identity of $G/A$. Then it will immediately imply that $\phi(H) = \phi(gHg^{-1})$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: More precisely, $\phi(A)=\{A\}$. The rest is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is correct if we can abuse the notations involving $\phi$. To better illustrate $A$ being an identity in $G/A$, I would've just written $\phi(A) = \overline{1}$ or however you denote the identity of $G/A$.

Without abusing such notations, such as not being able to directly point out $\phi(A) = \overline{1}$ or $\phi(HA) = \phi(H) \phi(A)$, it's a rather easy but longer task of proving that every element of $\phi(H)$ is contained in $\phi(gHg^{-1})$ by first using any element $ha \in HA$ and vice versa using any element $ghga \in gHg^{-1}A$ to prove the equality.